# Laravel PHPUnit : Can't use Config::get() when setUp() method is present

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a unit test similar to this in Laravel 9:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\CompanyContact;
use Config;

class CompanyContactTest extends TestCase
{
    private $aContact;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->aContact = new CompanyContact();
    }

    public function test_some_method()
    {
        $this->aContact->name = Config::get('app.default_name');
    }
}
```

That code won't work and will generate the following error:

> Class "Config" not found

But if I remove the setUp() method and initialize the $this->aContact attribute directly in test_some_method(), then the code will work. Example:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\CompanyContact;
use Config;

class CompanyContactTest extends TestCase
{
    private $aContact;

    public function test_some_method()
    {
        $this->aContact = new CompanyContact();
        $this->aContact->name = Config::get('app.default_name');
    }
}
```

Why is that the case? Why the Config facade in not accessible when I have a setUp() method?

Comment: Seems like you’re missing the parent call of setUp: `parent::setUp()`.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. That was indeed the problem. After reading the PHPUnit doc, I now understand that the call to parent::setUp() is important because the setUp() method in Laravel's TestCase class makes everything "Laravel" accessible and ready to be used by PHPUnit tests.